# ModelForm foreignkey field not loaded yet

Tags: django, foreign-keys, modelform

I'm attempting to develop a work record tracker sort of app, very similar to a ticket tracker. Each 'ticket' can have multiple notes owned by employees (employees are tracked in a different app that has been installed into the ticket-tracker).

i.e.

```
MySite
  |___WorkRecords
     |__models.py
     |__views.py
     |__etc..    //standard app stuff
  |___emp #the uncreative name for the employee manager app
     |__         //standard stuff again...
```

Within the models:

**WorkRecords.models.py**

```
class WorkRecord(models.Model):
    issuedate = models.DateField('date first issued',
             editable = False, default = timezone.now)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('emp.Employee', related_name='work_owner',
            on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    other_irrelevant_header_data...

    ....

class WorkRecordNote(models.Model):
    ref_wr = models.ForeignKey(WorkRecord, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey('emp.Employee', related_name='note_author',
            on_delete=models.PROTECT)

#Form class for the Work Record
class EditWR(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkRecord
        fields = '__all__'
```

**emp.models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model)
    data stuff
```

At the moment, the models have all been migrated, but the data has not been input into the tables yet (MySQL tables are all there, matching models etc...but no data within tables yet)

Now that I've gotten the models and tried working out modelform, I've tried makemigrations, but I'm getting an error traceback...

> ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'owner' yet, because its related model u'emp.Employee' has not been loaded yet

I checked my mysite/settings.py to ensure that the apps were installed, and the config files are all there:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'WorkRecords.apps.WorkrecordsConfig',
    'emp.apps.EmpConfig',
    etc...
]
...
```

To me, this sounds like it can't create the form because there isn't any data 'loaded' into the database, but what else I've learned about Django suggests that it shouldn't care yet. Is that accurate? Or is there something else I'm missing?

**EDIT:**
I made a change to the model of WorkRecord that somewhat fixed the problem (at least the error isn't there anymore, but I don't know about side-effects)

```
class WorkRecord(models.Model):
    ...
    owner=models.ForeignKey('emp.Employee', related_name='work_owner',
            on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False) #Added the editable=False
    ...
```

All else stayed the same, but makemigrations did not throw an error this time. What's the reasoning here?

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` should be a list of strings that are the absolute paths to your apps. Are you sure you have pasted your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting correctly?

Comment: @IainShelvington Sorry, my post contained a typo in `mysite/settings.py`, all the apps are listed as strings in my actual settings file. I'll edit the post to accurately reflect that.

Comment: Have you defined your `EditWR` ModelForm in your models.py? If you have then that is your problem. You should move it in to a separate forms.py

Comment: @IainShelvington I'll have to try that and let you know...I'm still not sure why either guillermo's answer below worked or why changing the `editable=False` property for the `owner` field worked. Could you shine some light on that by any chance? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Django loads your models in the same order that your apps are defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`. `ForeignKey` fields, when you use a string as the reference to the model, are lazy loaded, however when a `ModelForm` is created for a model it inspects the `ForeignKey` field and raises the exception when the model has not been loaded yet. It's good practice to define your forms in a separate forms.py for this reason

Comment: Oh and when a field is not editable Django will not create a form field for that model field

Comment: @IainShelvington That all makes sense. I really appreciate you spelling that out for me. Sounds like I have some configuration issues to address first thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order on your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    emp.apps.EmpConfig, # first
    WorkRecords.apps.WorkrecordsConfig,
    etc...
]
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked. Why does the order of the installed apps matter? Would it not be possible then to have a form in `emp/models.py` that uses a ForeignKey from the `workrecords/models.py` ?